# Variable within a variable in a CGI script

Tags: linux, bash, postgresql, shell, cgi

There is such a script:

```
NAME = `echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*post=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g"`
RES = `psql -U user -d db -t -c "SELECT tabl FROM tablica WHERE name = '$NAME'"`
echo $RES
```

Everything works fine (it means GET requests are fine). But the data from the database do not go.

The problem is that the value of the parameter in the query `WHERE NAME`  is not being set, and I get a syntax error.

I have read many articles on the Internet, but found nothing about a variable inside backticks.

How can I fix this?

Comment: The shell does not expand dollar-varables inside '$singlequotes'. Best way to get around it is to use a here-document (that does expand $ inside double and single quotes)

Comment: That code cannot possibly "work fine" in bash. Please copy and paste your real code

Answer (score 2):

You're not allowed to put spaces around the equal sign in variable assignments. And you should generally not use backticks, but prefer the `$()` form, it is easier to deal with quoting with it.

```
NAME=$(echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*post=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g")
RES=$(psql -U user -d db -t -c "SELECT tabl FROM tablica WHERE name = '$NAME'")
echo "$RES"
```

Note that what you're doing is pretty insecure, you need stronger validation for your inputs.

Comment: You'll need to be much more precise than "doesn't work". Please give exact errors, exact inputs, and your current code in your question.